# Why do Polish people view Russia unfavorably?

Tags: russian-federation, public-opinion, poland

> Poles hold the most negative views of Russia among all countries
> included in a new global survey by the Pew Research Center, which also
> shows that attitudes towards the United States, NATO and the European
> Union are the most positive ever recorded in Poland.
>
> Only 2% of Poles hold a favourable view of Russia, while 97% have an
> unfavourable opinion. For the US, those figures are reversed, with 91%
> positive and 3% negative. Meanwhile, 94% now see Russia as a major
> threat to Poland, up from 65% when the question was last asked in
> 2018.
>
> [image]

https://notesfrompoland.com/2022/06/22/only-2-of-poles-view-russia-favourably-lowest-of-any-country-in-global-study/

According to a Pew research paper, 97% of the Poles have a unfavorable view of Russia while only 2% hold a favorable view of Russia, the highest of any country surveyed. Is there a particular reason why Polish people view Russia unfavorably?

Comment: Not to be obnoxious, but while many of your questions are good, quite a few would benefit from a minimum of basic research before asking.  This is one is so obvious that I doubt it benefits anyone who is seriously interested in getting an answer.

Comment: This question (and a couple similar questions) [are being discussed on meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/what-should-we-do-with-all-those-why-do-country-people-view-country-favorab).

Comment: How is this even a question?

Comment: Are Poles truly the least positive towards Russia of the countries surveyed? I don't see a margin of error or even a response count (_n_) given. That conclusion may not be statistically significant.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The same reasoning could be used for not having a Wikipedia page for an "obvious" subject. 1. Not everybody in the world or in every field has (or should be expected to have) the level of knowledge of "obvious" European history that many westerners who participate in Politics.SE have, any more that we should expect you to have the basic knowledge of, say, South East Asian history that is common among educated Indonesians.

Comment: 2. Even for those with that knowledge, having a well-written reference that gives the "obvious" answer to a question is very handy when talking to others. In particular, it helps avoid wasting time reworking and retyping answers when discussing particular topics even with those you suspect may not be "seriously interested in getting an answer," or where the answer is tangential to the argument.

Comment: 3. The point of SE is to serve as a good reference for the Internet on the SE's topics. Saying, essentially, "too obvious for this SE" is saying, "this answer should be elsewhere," and undermining the whole point of SE. 4. This particular question is fine for "basic research" _supporting the question itself._ Complaining that a question doesn't include the answer is nonsensical; we have _answers_ for the answers and their supporting research.

Comment: @cjs done with the lecture (4 messages)?  The OP has a tendency to ask a lot of questions.  That's fine, but a minimum of trying to figure things out by oneself also keeps the clutter down hereabouts.  Even if you don't know Western history googling "XXX YYY relations" goes a a long way - in this case direct to the wiki page of those 2.  Many SE. sites have a good-faith-effort-before-asking expectation, doesn't really hurt things any.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Again, your "clutter" (from the point of view of someone with fairly deep knowledge of this stuff) is someone else's useful new information. The whole point of SE is to _create_ the very things that come up when you tell someone to "google XXX." If you feel the question is too simple for you, simply ignore it, rather than deciding that an audience with significantly less knowledge than you shouldn't be looking on this site for answers to questions that would otherwise be clearly within its remit. This site is for a _lot_ of people other than you.

Comment: @cjs methink you need to repeat this once more.  i didn't quite get you.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Your snide comments and general "don't ask questions with answers obvious to me" attitude is one I've seen before in other folks with fairly high rep on some SEs. If you still can't accept any of the above, I don't think that there's any way I can convince you that there are other folks in the world with vastly different experience from yours that find these sorts of questions useful. But it would be good if you could at least _try_ to step back and realise that, just because you're here a lot and have a high rep, that does not make this SE your personal playground.

Comment: @cjs C̵a̵n̵ ̵y̵o̵u̵ ̵e̵x̵p̵l̵a̵i̵n̵ ̵i̵t̵ ̵a̵g̵a̵i̵n̵?̵ Sigh, much fun as it would be to elicit more lecturing... you could have just edited it?  2 words...  I made my point at the time, I don't care all that much if it remains there now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is clearly not the *only* reason, but the foreign policy of Putin since 2014 appears to be a major driver in the exacerbation of those negative views, as the [history](https://www.pewresearch.org/short-reads/2015/03/19/anti-russian-views-on-the-rise-in-poland/) of those Pew polls suggests.

[image]

That poll even notes that "Nearly all interviews in Poland were conducted after Putin’s statement on March 18, 2014, regarding the Russian annexation of Crimea."

Comment: Somewhat related https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/69474/why-are-pis-and-fidesz-split-over-russia-and-ukraine

Comment: On the contrary, it seems that the attutude wasn't great already, even pre-2014. I wonder if Bulgaria and Czech could be plotted alongside to illustrate.

Comment: The 54:36 opinions in 2013 wasn't "great", but going to 81:12 in a single year is a huge change. Every poll I've seen shows a significant, massive drop in that one year, well beyond the scope of normal yearly variances. No other year on that graph is close.

Comment: Year 2010 is also interesting. But I don't know if I'll find enough time to expand on it and add an answer.

Answer (score 29):

History much?  Poland spent a good deal of its not-long-past subjugated by either [Germany or Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Poland_(1795%E2%80%931918)).

> From 1795 to 1918, Poland was split between Prussia, the Habsburg monarchy, and Russia and had no independent existence. In 1795 the third and the last of the three 18th-century partitions of Poland ended the existence of the Polish–Lithuanian Commonwealth.

In 1939, the USSR invades it, with its Nazi buddies. `*`

Past 1945, Warsaw Pact until 1989.

see also [Katyn massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katyn_massacre)

Obviously, as others have pointed out, Russian actions since [2007's Estonian cyberwar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007_cyberattacks_on_Estonia) and hankering for the "glory days of the USSR" are only reinforcing this dislike.

---

`*` Hitler rose to power partially on fear and hate for Bolshevism so the world was stunned when [Molotov-Ribbentrop Pact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molotov%E2%80%93Ribbentrop_Pact) was signed in August 1939, a week before Germany invaded Poland.  That deal gave eastern half of Poland to the USSR, along with free rein for Russia to screw the Baltics (which Russia did soon afterwards).  Stalin might have benefited from reading Mein Kampf as - not before Russia fed the Nazi war machine with raw materials for 2 years - Hitler double-crossed him with his Barbarossa invasion in 1941, bringing us back to the more familiar history we all know (and one considerably more palatable to Herr Putin).

p.s. Besides practical considerations, why did the UK and France not also declare war on the USSR when it attacked Poland?  Because their mutual-defense pact with Poland had a secret clause identifying (only) Germany as the power of interest.

p.p.s.  Much ink has been spilled on whether a) Stalin was just dumb.  Or b) got pre-empted before he [could double-cross Hitler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_offensive_plans_controversy#Suvorov,_Icebreaker,_and_the_1980s) himself.  One suspects the life expectancy in the 40s-50s of option A historians or documents in Russia might have been limited, so there is no real way to know (the abject failure of Soviet forces in the first weeks of Barbarossa hints at A).  One valid-ish concern Russia had in 1939 was a suspicion that the Western powers were just hoping Russia and Germany would start fighting, before swooping in to pick the bones afterwards.

---

To be fair, while Stalin started out helping Hitler and facilitated WW2, keep in mind [60-70%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_casualties_in_World_War_II) of German military casualties were sustained on the Eastern Front.  The USSR lost [13.7% of its population](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II_casualties#Total_deaths_by_country) in that war, compared to UK w 1% and US w 0.3%.

Comment: It's not only that, Putin rubs it in the face of Poles, accusing them of starting WW2 etc. https://notesfrompoland.com/2019/12/23/putin-blames-poland-for-ww2-and-says-soviet-occupation-saved-lives/ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oM2h3KnWAWY&t=295s

Comment: And we had like 20 years of that, mutual sniping between Poland and Russia (under Putin) largely based on the politicisation of history; this 2005 NYT article is informative https://www.nytimes.com/2005/07/03/world/europe/after-centuries-of-enmity-relations-between-poland-and-russia.html

Comment: There's also the [Smolensk air disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smolensk_air_disaster) in 2010, widely blamed on the Russians by Poles. Distrust breeds more distrust.

Comment: @StuartF Impact of Smolensk disaster on Polish attitude towards Russia deserves a separate answer.

Comment: It's rather rude to start answers with a snide, "History much?" especially when that encodes an assumption that _everybody on the Internet_ should have an education in history and, in particular, an education in _western_ history. SE sites are supposed to be a reference sites useful to _everybody,_ not discussion forums only for people familiar with the topic of the SE.

Answer (score 15):

For Poland and Baltic states, disfavor to Russian Federation results from seeing this country as a threat.

These countries are located close to Russia and have the not so old history of being forcibly incorporated into Soviet block. They see themselves as the first candidates if Russia would ever attempt testing if NATO works as expected.

After heavy post-soviet crisis, these countries joined EU and achieved economic success. If Russia now forcibly pulls them back into its sphere, they have that to lose. While was indeed the time in 2011 or about when GDP per capita shortly went below Russia's, it is currently [much above](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.PCAP.CD?end=2022&locations=PL-RU&start=2009&view=chart) and climbing.

This is probably enough for not to look for more reasons.
The survey in question asks about the *country*. The position towards local ethnic Russians, or even Russians in general, may be less extreme.